# Getting error when going from one tableview controller to another

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I'm having real problems using tableviews. I've never been able to understand them and just when I think I'm getting somewhere I get another problem.

I have a tableview controller and when the user selects a row I want this to go to a second tableview controller. Even though both controllers are set up the same way I can't seem to get the second controller to populate the cells. In view did load I have the following code that is getting the error message: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x75726f52)

```
self.Rows = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Home",@"About",@"Forum",@"Contact US", nil];
```

Searching this error message I have seen that it can appear for a number of reason but mainly seems to be around something being released. There have been mentions of ARC etc. But, from what I've read I have no idea how to resolve this and no idea why going from tableview to tableview would cause this.

Thanks

Comment: is self.rows is `NSArray` and if yes than is it strong type property?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and see what line gives you the exception. Also use the modern Objective-C syntax: `self.Rows = @[@"Home",@"About",@"Forum",@"Contact US"];`

Comment: please show more code: your `viewDidLoad`, `Rows` property declaration, and how you open the second table view controller

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses but I've just discovered the problem. In my code I had an additional entry in the array that I haven't copied into the above and it was missing the @ sign. I feel very stupid.